# IntelliJ format code w.r.t. lenght of characters

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, format

I am trying to figure out a way to format setters and builders with respect to the length of characters. What I mean by that is, consider the following code:

```java
          props
              .setDataStream(dataStream)
              .setQueue(new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1024))
              .setSpan(span)
              .setStreamIsDepleted(new AtomicBoolean(false))
              .setTotalPolled(new AtomicLong(0))
              .setFieldMetadataList(dataStream.getSchema());

- - - - -

    return ObjectPath.builder()
        .catalog(destinationConfig.getCatalog())
        .schema(destinationConfig.getSchema())
        .table(destinationConfig.getTable())
        .build();
```

The output I want after formatting is:

```java
          props
              .setSpan(span)
              .setDataStream(dataStream)
              .setTotalPolled(new AtomicLong(0))
              .setQueue(new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1024))
              .setFieldMetadataList(dataStream.getSchema())
              .setStreamIsDepleted(new AtomicBoolean(false));
- - - - -

    return ObjectPath.builder()
        .table(destinationConfig.getTable())
        .schema(destinationConfig.getSchema())
        .catalog(destinationConfig.getCatalog())
        .build();
```

Is this even possible or am I just wasting my time?

Comment: This is not possible

Answer (score 0):

The [String Manipulation plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation) has a `Sort Lines` action which can sort lines by length. You can select the lines you want sorted and invoke the action.

However, this might be a bit of an overkill. The plugin will popup a dialog with an enormous amount of options every time. You could also create a simple action to sort selected lines by length using the [IDE Scripting Console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ide-scripting-console.html) and bind it to some keystroke using the Keymap settings.

I created a quick prototype using Groovy (which I never use so it probably can be simpler). Invoke `Tools | IDE Scripting Console` choose `Groovy` in the popup that appears and paste in the following code:

```
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionManager
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent
import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.CommonDataKeys
import com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.Caret
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.Document
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.Editor
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project
import com.intellij.openapi.util.TextRange
import com.intellij.openapi.util.text.StringUtil
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

class SortByLengthAction extends AnAction {

  @Override
  void update(@NotNull AnActionEvent e) {
    // Get required data key
    final Editor editor = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR)

    // Set visibility only in case of existing project and editor and if a selection exists
    e.getPresentation().setEnabledAndVisible( e.getProject() != null
                                                && editor != null
                                                && editor.getSelectionModel().hasSelection() )
  }

  @Override
  void actionPerformed(@NotNull AnActionEvent e) {
    // Get all the required data from data keys
    Editor editor = e.getRequiredData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR)
    Project project = e.getRequiredData(CommonDataKeys.PROJECT)
    Document document = editor.getDocument()

    // Work off of the primary caret to get the selection info
    Caret primaryCaret = editor.getCaretModel().getPrimaryCaret()
    int start = primaryCaret.getSelectionStart()
    int end = primaryCaret.getSelectionEnd()

    String selection = document.getText(new TextRange(start, end))
    String[] lines = StringUtil.splitByLines(selection)
    Arrays.sort(lines, {a, b -> a.length() - b.length()})
    String result = StringUtil.join(lines, "\n")
    // Replace the selection with a fixed string.
    // Must do this document change in a write action context.
    WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(project, { document.replaceString(start, end, result) })

    // De-select the text range that was just replaced
    primaryCaret.removeSelection()
  }
}

def actionManager = ActionManager.getInstance()
actionManager.replaceAction("SortByLength", new SortByLengthAction())
```

Select the complete code using <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and run it using <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After running it, you can find the newly created action in `Preferences | Keymap` in the `Other` section. There you can assign it some sensible keyboard short cut.